# Sinatra + haml + jQuery, rendering haml from javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, sinatra, haml

I am working on a project using sinatra with haml for templates. I want to be able to append some of my haml partials using JQuery. I am hoping to add this to a js function being triggered by an event like so

```
....addEventListener(myWidget, 'click', function() {
    $('targetDiv').append(RenderHamlTempalte('/my/file/location/');
});
```

or

```
....addEventListener(myWidget, 'click', function() {
    $('targetDiv').append(RenderHamlTempalte('/my/file/location/', {options: here, options: here);
});
```

I have checked out a few related projects on github but really can't find something to do this with properly.

thanks for any info

UPDATE:

here was what I ended up going with

```
var url = '/update&my&div/' + param;
$('.my-div').load(url);
```

and then in my sinatra app.rb I can just return my haml partial

```
get ''/update&my&div/:params' do
    # do some stuff
    @make_variables_happen
    haml :my_partial
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a tool like: https://github.com/uglyog/clientside-haml-js
You would have to wrap your partials in `<script type="text/haml-template" id="template_id"> YOUR PARTIAL GOES HERE </script>` and append them somewhere in your html page (I usually add them at the bottom of the page). You can then reference them from JavaScript with:

```
 var tmpl = haml.compileHaml('template_id');
```

and then you can pass the data with:

```
var html = tmpl({option1: value1, option1: value1});
```

or based on your example:

```
$('targetDiv').append(tmpl({option1: value1, option1: value1}));
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I ended up going a slightly different route because having to include my haml partials in the same file wasn't ideal. I edited my first post to show how if anyone is interested. thanks again for the tip